# Mp3 link crawler for dynamic links

Tags: php

i am writing an crawler that will go around a specific set of websites and crawl all the mp3 links into the database. I don't want to download the files, just crawl the link, index them and be able to search them. using php and how some sites linke guruji.com

Comment: Good for you...so what is your question? You want us to write the crawler :D ?

Comment: i need to know how to do for dynamic links..i have written crawler for static mp3 links...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a statement of intent with no question. 

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to research regular expressions - so, after you've connected, do something like:

```
function crawl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); // 30 second timeout
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    $result = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);

    if ($result) {
        // top domain links
        preg_match_all( '/<a(?:[^>]*)href=\"([^\"]*)\"(?:[^>]*)>(?:[^<]*)<\/a>/is', $result, $output, PREG_SET_ORDER );

        foreach( $output as $item ) {
            // each link found is output
            echo "<pre>";
            var_dump($item[0]);
            // do your magic here
        }
    }
}
```

This will only find all links though, so you'd have to adjust the match to your usage, or come up with a filter.